# jQuery Tabs plugin help

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want a Simple jquery plugin. i have looked at a few and even the jQuery UI. i dont intend to use the UI element of jQuery so i want some recommendation for a simple tabs plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're after something a bit lighter, many users like the [jQuery Tools Tabs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html).

There are even lighter ones out there, or make your own, but the [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) series of plugins are usually a nice set of "not too heavy" and "enough features" middle ground.

Comment: can i use jQuery UI plugins with out the use of the theme ?

Comment: cool. but someone said that we need the css for the structural things of the elements :(

Comment: @Harsha - Yes they are CSS dependent...what is your goal really? They have to look like *something*, are you aware of themeroller, where you can customize the theme? http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: yes i am aware of it. i am not sure hot to integrate it into my theme. as the theme roller will take few hrs to config ... damn...